# Unable to invoke HTML FRAME link using Selenium Java Test case

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, frame

I have a private JSP URL that has frames.

snapshot:

[image]

As you can see in the snapshot I wish to click on "Replication management" then "Manage queues" which is in the left frame.

View Page Source:

```
<!-- Mark the file as a JSP and set up the classes to import -->

<HEAD>
<link rel="icon" href="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/tds-16.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/tds-16.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</HEAD>

<HTML dir='ltr'>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>
IBM Security Directory Server Web Administration Tool
</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<FRAMESET ROWS="40,*">

<FRAME SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSBannerFrame.jsp" TITLE="Banner Frame" NAME="BannerFrame" MARGINWIDTH="1" MARGINHEIGHT="1" SCROLLING="NO" NORESIZE FRAMEBORDER="1" FRAMESPACING="1" BORDERCOLOR="#000000">

<FRAMESET COLS="20%,80%">

<FRAME SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp" TITLE="Navigation frame" NAME="NavFrame" MARGINWIDTH="1" MARGINHEIGHT="1" SCROLLING="AUTOMATIC" FRAMEBORDER="1" FRAMESPACING="1" BORDERCOLOR="#000000">

<FRAME SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSWorkFrame.jsp" TITLE="Work Area Frameset" NAME="WorkArea" MARGINWIDTH="1" MARGINHEIGHT="1" SCROLLING="AUTOMATIC" FRAMEBORDER="1" FRAMESPACING="1" BORDERCOLOR="#000000">

<NOFRAMES>
<BODY>
The IBM Security Directory Server Web Administration Tool does not currently support Web browsers that do not support frames. Contact the Directory Server administrator to find a Web browser that supports frames.
</BODY>
</NOFRAMES>

</FRAMESET>

<NOFRAMES>
<BODY>
The IBM Security Directory Server Web Administration Tool does not currently support Web browsers that do not support frames. Contact the Directory Server administrator to find a Web browser that supports frames.
</BODY>
</NOFRAMES>

</FRAMESET>

</HTML>
```

View Frame Source:

```
<!-- Mark the file as a JSP and set up the classes to import -->

<HTML dir='ltr'>

<HEAD>
<style type="text/css">
FONT { font-size: 100%; }
.navHeading {PADDING-TOP: 4px;PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px;PADDING-LEFT: 2px;FONT-WEIGHT: bold;FONT-SIZE: 70%;FONT-FAMILY: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;BACKGROUND-COLOR: #D1D9E8}
.navTask {PADDING-LEFT: 2px;FONT-SIZE: 60%;FONT-FAMILY: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;BACKGROUND-COLOR: #D1D9E8}
</style>
<TITLE>
Navigation frame
</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<Body bgColor="#D1D9E8">

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width="100%" bgcolor="#D1D9E8" xbgcolor="#000000">

<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSWelcome" Target="WorkFrame" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnDocument.gif" title="Click here to launch Introduction" alt="Click here to launch Introduction" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" >Introduction</Font></A>
</td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?opennav=idspasswd#spot" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnTnClosed.gif" title="Click here to open User properties" alt="Click here to open User properties" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnFolderClosed.gif" title="Click here to open User properties" alt="" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><Font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">User properties</Font></A></td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?opennav=idssrvadm#spot" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnTnClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Server administration" alt="Click here to open Server administration" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnFolderClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Server administration" alt="" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><Font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Server administration</Font></A></td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?opennav=idsproxy#spot" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnTnClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Proxy administration" alt="Click here to open Proxy administration" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnFolderClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Proxy administration" alt="" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><Font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Proxy administration</Font></A></td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?opennav=idsdmt#spot" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnTnClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Schema management" alt="Click here to open Schema management" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnFolderClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Schema management" alt="" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><Font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Schema management</Font></A></td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?opennav=idsdirmgmt#spot" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnTnClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Directory management" alt="Click here to open Directory management" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnFolderClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Directory management" alt="" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><Font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Directory management</Font></A></td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?opennav=idsreplication#spot" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnTnClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Replication management" alt="Click here to open Replication management" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnFolderClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Replication management" alt="" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><Font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Replication management</Font></A></td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?opennav=idstid#spot" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnTnClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Realms and templates" alt="Click here to open Realms and templates" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnFolderClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Realms and templates" alt="" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><Font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Realms and templates</Font></A></td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?opennav=idsusrgrp#spot" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnTnClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Users and groups" alt="Click here to open Users and groups" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnFolderClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Users and groups" alt="" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><Font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Users and groups</Font></A></td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSLogout" Target="_top" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnDocument.gif" title="Click here to launch Logout" alt="Click here to launch Logout" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Logout</Font></A>
</td></tr>

</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Based on inputs from StackOverflow's other thread I was recommended to use the below code:

```
   WebDriverWait waitforme = new WebDriverWait(driver,5,2000);
   System.out.println("before wait");
   waitforme.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("BannerFrame"));
   System.out.println("after wait");
//Checking nested frames here
        if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='BannerFrame']")).size()>0)
        {
            System.out.println("inside frame 1");
         driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='BannerFrame']")));
            if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='NavFrame']")).size()>0)
            {
                System.out.println("inside frame 2");
            driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='NavFrame']")));
                if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='WorkArea']")).size()>0)
                {
                    System.out.println("inside frame 3");
            driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='WorkArea']")));

            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='WorkArea']")).size()>0)
            {
                System.out.println("inside frame 3");
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='WorkArea']")));
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='NavFrame']")).size()>0)
        {
            System.out.println("inside frame 2");
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='NavFrame']")));

            if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='WorkArea']")).size()>0)
            {
                System.out.println("inside frame 3");
       driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='WorkArea']")));

            }       

        }
        else
        {
            if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='WorkArea']")).size()>0)
            {
                System.out.println("inside frame 3");
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='WorkArea']")));

            }   
        }
    }

    //Click on Replication management link
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[./font[text()='Replication management']]"))).click();
```

After it prints "after wait", none of the if conditions are met and then it eventually timeouts on the WebDriverWait.

Can you please suggest why all the if conditions are failing and how can we invoke the desired links? None of the suggestions have helped so far.

I'm on jdk1.8 64 bit.

Comment: Keep your `if else` in `Try and Catch`. You getting error because element is not present on the webpage. Go this [Link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58769337/continue-if-element-not-found-if-found-save-it#58769509 for more information

Comment: I will work on try-catch but can you load my html from local drive and see why the element goes missing when the view source and view frame source show our element? This issue should be easily reproducible.

Comment: you've switched the driver to the frame already... then you test to see if the frame has itself inside, which it does not.  All that is inside that frame is the top banner AND another frameset... and these are frames ("<FRAME>"), not iframes ("<IFRAME>").  So "//iframe" won't work here...

Comment: @pcalkins this is what I suspected. So how do I switch to frames instead of iframes as selenium Java code?

Comment: With Frames i was able to click the links.... But now i m not able to determine the frame / iframe that opens in the right section where i wish to read the table data. If i copy link from manage queue and load in driver then it works fine but  the same code fails when i try to reach out using switching frames/iframes

Comment: I was eventually able to get this to work. The problem was rightly identified by @pcalkins that it is a frame and not a i frame.